# Which files refer to unallocated partition?

Tags: partitioning, fdisk

```
# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 34.4 GB, 34359738368 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 4177 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d5d11

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1265    10155008   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            1265        1457     1544192   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

My virtual machine have 34.4 GB disk, I had already divided it into 2 partitions /dev/sda1 (9.68 GiB) for root path and /dev/sda2 (1.47 GiB) for swap area, so that I have remain free space about 20.84 GiB

I can format unallocated space via Gparted, but If I want to use command line such as `mke2fs` to handle this job, how I can refer to that free space to complete this command line.

```
mke2fs -jv /dev/<xxx>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't.  You create a partition using the free space, and format that.

Comment: how I can do that? I need command line version for this job.

Comment: @Smile, with `fdisk` of course, or `parted` is a bit friendlier.

Comment: finally, I ended up with `gparted` :/